# Bash variable in 2 quotes

Tags: bash, curl

I want to send a request like this with `curl`:

```
curl some parameters and headers --data-binary '{"secret":"$1"}'
```

but `$1` is not being variable. I tried using `echo` with this command:

```
echo '{"asd":"$1"}' dhkdgb
```

and I got this output:

```
{"asd":"$1"} dhkdgb
```

However, I want to get this output:

```
{"asd":"dhkdgb"}
```

And at `curl` request, I want to send this:

```
curl some parameters and headers --data-binary '{"secret":"argv 0 of script"}'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: $1 is a variable containing the first argument to your script... but you don't use a script, right? You just type the curl command at the prompt? So $1 is empty/unset. Also, variables inside single quotes are not interpreted. You would use single quotes if you want to use "$1" literally, without Bash interpreting it as a variable.

Comment: If you do call this from a script and `$1` is indeed defined, then replace your single quotes with double quotes and your double quotes with either single quotes or escaped double quotes. Replace `'{"secret":"$1"}'` with `"{\"secret\":\"$1\"}"` or with `"{'secret':'$1'}"`

Comment: @mivk The official JSON spec actually requires double quotes for strings (both in keys and values), so for it to be properly portable you would have to use escaped double quotes instead of the single quote approach.

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to do it ex. given

```
$ set -- 'foo bar'
```

(to assign value `foo bar` to the shell's first positional parameter, as if in a script invoked like `myscript "foo bar"`) then for example

```
$ echo '{"asd:":"'"$1"'"}'
{"asd:":"foo bar"}
```

or

```
$ echo {\"asd:\":\""$1"\"}
{"asd:":"foo bar"}
```

However you may find it cleaner to use the shell's `printf` builtin to create a formatted string that you can assign to a new variable:

```
$ printf -v data '{"asd": "%s"}' "$1"
$ echo "$data"
{"asd": "foo bar"}
```

which you can then use as

```
curl some parameters and headers --data-binary "$data"
```

---

Alternatively, since you appear to be trying to pass a JSON object to the curl command, you could consider using `jq` in place of `printf`:

```
$ jq -nc --arg x "$1" '{asd: $x}'
{"asd":"foo bar"}
```

or similarly using the built-in `$ARGS` array

```
$ jq -nc --arg asd "$1" '$ARGS.named'
{"asd":"foo bar"}
```

if you want to pass both the name and value to the constructor.

Comment: `jq` has a nicer way of doing this: `jq -n --arg asd "$1" '.$ARGS.named'`

Comment: Unless I missed something, I think this is much easier to solve - see my answer.

Comment: @vanadium - sure, as I mentioned there are several ways to do it with esacpes. I just happen not to be a fan of "leaning toothpicks" so tried to offer some alternatives

Comment: @muru that's nice - thanks. Added.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and `-d@-` (read input data from stdin) for composing JSON request bodies:

```
cat <<EOF |
{
    "secret": "$SECRET"
}
EOF
curl ... \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "${BASE_URL%%/}/the/path" -d@-
```

Yes, the syntax is a little weird.