# Is it feasible to send a post in the form of some variables rather than raw string?

Tags: bash

This code sends a post request to a specified url

```
urlStr='http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/compile'
curl $urlStr -d '{"cmd": "g++-4.8 main.cpp && ./a.out", "src": "#include <iostream>\nint main(){    std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;}"}'
```

where the url is given via the $urlStr variable

I'm trying to replace the other parts with variables

```
codeStr='#include <iostream>\nint main() {\n  std::cout << \"Hello World!\" << std::endl;\n}'
cmdStr='g++ main.cpp && ./a.out'
curl $urlStr -d '{"cmd": $cmdStr, "src": $codeStr}'
```

and I got an error

> 765: unexpected token at '{"cmd": $cmdStr, "src": $codeStr}'

How do I make it work?

Comment: `"{\"cmd\": \"$cmdStr\", \"src\": \"$codeStr\"}"`, think you want to expand your variables.

Comment: ... see also [Bash variable in 2 quotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385884/bash-variable-in-2-quotes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash variable in 2 quotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385884/bash-variable-in-2-quotes)